# Здравствуйте почему не работает программа на си?

Tags: c, файлы, структуры, текстовые-файлы

Мне нужно в этой программе описать структуру и работать с ней но уже выдает ошибки при подключении текстового файла. Кампилятору не нравиться типы данных почему то и не нравиться сканф и fopen. В чем может быть проблема подскажите пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct worker {
    char name[50];
    char work[20];
    int time;
    int pay;
    int born;
};

struct worker workers_list[10];



int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    FILE* file;
    int i = 0;

    file = fopen("fscanf.txt", "w");
    while (fscanf(file, "%s%s%d%d%d",
        &(workers_list[i].name), &(workers_list[i].work),
        workers_list[i].time, workers_list[i].pay, workers_list[i].born) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s%s%d%d%d\n", workers_list[i].time, workers_list[i].pay, workers_list[i].born);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы открываете файл на запись и пытаетесь читать из него. При открытии существующего файла просто на запись, всё содержимое затирается. Если файла не было - он создастся.
Во-вторых у вас неправильно указаны параметры, и компилятор сообщает вам об этом. Спецификатор "%s" требует в параметрах `char*`. А вы передаете `char**`, т.к. имя символьного массива является указателем на него.

```
// неправильно
fscanf(file, "%s%s%d%d%d", &(workers_list[i].name),
// правильно
fscanf(file, "%s%s%d%d%d", workers_list[i].name,
```

А для `int` - наоборот нужно передать адрес

```
// неправильно
fscanf(file, "%s%s%d%d%d", , , workers_list[i].time,
// правильно
fscanf(file, "%s%s%d%d%d", , , &(workers_list[i].time),
```

Ну и в `printf` у вас аргументов меньше, чем спецификаций

Comment: Имя символьного массива не является указателем.

Comment: @user7860670 Для упрощения объяснения написал

Comment: Спасибо, помогло насчет типов, а с print это я тупанул промежуточный код отправил и с записью вместо чтения файло, но он ругаеться. Пишет что не безопасно использовать fopen и fscanf.

Comment: Ну да - не безопасно. Вы например не проверяете, сколько параметров прочитано. А если scanf из 5 параметров прочитал только 3? А вы продолжаете работать, как будто ничего не случилось. Опять-таки, компилируете вы в компиляторе C++ - а по его мнению для работы с файлами безопаснее использовать потоки (и это действительно так). Но и без этих функций - у вас есть косяки. Например куда вы будете писать информацию, если вдруг в файле будет больше 10 записей?

Comment: А как тогда правильно написать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто нужно всё проверять. Проверять количество записей, чтобы не выйти за пределы массива, проверять на каждом шаге всё ли считалось функцией `scanf()` и т.д. Но поскольку у вас похоже учебное задание, работающее с искусственными входными данными, можно просто сделать допущения - 1. Записей в файле не больше, чем размер массива 2. Все записи в файле корректны - не вызывают ошибок при вводе. И тогда все проверки пропускаете.